# What exactly is the z argument in plot_ly?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have three variables: `x`,`y`, and `z` and I want to produce a surface plot.

```
z<-runif(50,0,1) 
y<-runif(50,1,2)
x<-runif(50,3,6)
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z= ~z) %>% add_surface()
```

I get the following error

`` Error: `z` must be a numeric matrix ``

What exactly does `z` represent if not the variable corresponding to the vertical axis? I have seen the Volcano example where they use the matrix to generate that plot, but I still am not sure what that z matrix represents in that example either.

What I would like is for someone to plot an easy to understand 3D function like `z=f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2` using the `surface` functionality in `plot_ly` just so I can understand how to generate a plot based on three variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with your above code is, that you haven't specified the **trace type** - and what you need to pass to the z argument depends on this **specification**.

Passing the arguments x, y, z suggests you want to display a scatter3d plot - you can test this by dropping `add_surface()`:

```
z <- runif(50,0,1) 
y <- runif(50,1,2)
x <- runif(50,3,6)
plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z)
```

Which gives the warning:

> No trace type specified:   Based on info supplied, a 'scatter3d' trace
> seems appropriate.   Read more about this trace type ->
> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter3d No scatter3d mode specifed:
> Setting the mode to markers   Read more about this attribute ->
> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-mode

`add_surface()` on the other hand suggests you want to display a 3D Surface Plot.
You already mentioned the [volcano example](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/#basic-3d-surface-plot). This kind of plot only needs a single numeric matrix to create the plot (argument z).

Accordingly with your example code you mixed up both plot types which leads to the error message.

**How to avoid this confusion?**

If you have a look at `?plot_ly` there is a description for arguments "..." passed to the according trace type (z is one of them):

> Arguments (i.e., attributes) passed along to the trace type. See
> schema() for a list of acceptable attributes for a given trace type
> (by going to traces -> type -> attributes).

`schema()` is a very useful hint to orient oneself in the plotly library. Execute the following code to **browse through the different plotly trace types** and their available attributes in a very **convenient way**:
[image: schema_output]

```
# install.packages("listviewer")

library(plotly)
library(listviewer)
schema(jsonedit = interactive())
```

I guess this is what you were after in the first place:

```
z <- runif(50,0,1) 
y <- runif(50,1,2)
x <- runif(50,3,6)
plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z, type = 'mesh3d')
```